# add html to an individual cell in a datatable in powershell

Tags: html, powershell, datatable

In powershell I have a datatable that contains a columns of ID's. I am trying to add a specific hyperlink to each of the ID's.

for example if the value in the cell of the ID column is 12345 it will link to www.google.com/12345

I have tried adding the html to the string inside the datatable, but whenits outputted instead of making it a hyperlink it simply shows the href code

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show what you tried, searched. e.g. Posting your code that you are working. You just look like you are dumping your homework here.